# Layout XML com problemas

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

estou com um problema, tenho um layout com alguns campos edit Text, o que acontece é que o Scrollview que uso funciona para todos os campos da Activity exceto para o botão que acaba por ir para baixo da tela. Alguém tem uma boa ideia de o que posso fazer? OBG desd já.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fields_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.24">


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/nomeNsocio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TxtNome"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Nome/Empresa"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailNsocio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TxtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:singleLine="true" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/telefoneNsocio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TxtTelefone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Telefone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/senhaNsocio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TxtSenha"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Senha"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/senha2Nsocio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TxtSenha2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Confirmar Senha"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnRegistrarSe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:background="#033f88"
            android:text="Registrar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Jairo, testei o seu código aqui e está funcionando normalmente, tente exemplificar melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Então todos os campos do formulário estão com validação, e apresentam uma msg de erro em baixo do edit text que apresentar algum erro, quando isso ocorre ele empurra os outros componentes para baixo, já coloquei a propriedade que já deixa esse espaço que será ocupado pela msg de erro, assim o botao fica para fora da tela(No emulador, ou celular) não no pteview, p certo seria ao eu rolar a página esse botao aparecer, pois ele está dentro do scrollview como todos os outros componentes, mas isso não ocorre é como se, simplesmente a rolagem acabasse antes do Button.